# Why do birds flap/shake their wings?

Tags: ornithology, behaviour

[Here is a video](https://youtu.be/mcM23M-CCog?t=750) that will show the behaviour I'm interested (see between 12:30 and 12:32).

I want to know if this behaviour has a name and why birds are doing this. I observed this many times, with offsprings getting fed, females and males adults. I'm curious about studies that looked at that behaviour.

Comment: I'm not enough of an ornithologist to answer this, but I'm pretty sure this is a begging behaviour. Using that term should get you somewhere searching for studies. The 2 seconds in your video isn't the most clear example, but here is more: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dhNOLL6CZog